# Изменение значений в датасете формул

Tags: python, строки, pandas, re

У меня есть столбец с данными типа: ZnFe2O4, Fe2O3, Fe3O4@CeO2, Fe-CuO2.
Однако, формулы с разделителями типа: /, @, -, мне нужно привести к виду от Fe-CuO2 к FeCuO2.
Я написала такой блок:

```
for formula in df['Core']:
  if formula.isalnum( ) == False:
    line = re.split("-,@,/", formula) #разделила через регулярные выражения
    comp1 =''
    count = 0
    while count <= len(line):
      for i in line:
        count += 1 
        comp1 += i
    df['Core'] = comp1
```

Однако в итоге все значения в столбце стали пустыми:

```
df['Core'].values
```

array(['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
'', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',...

В чём моя ошибка?

Обновление 1.
Мне нужно, чтобы все значения в столбце типа Au@CuFe2O3 стали AuCuFe2O3, поэтому я решила разделить значения, что имели разделители в списки, а потом соединить в строку, но присваивание значений для каждого значения в pandas через цикл идёт не правильно. Как правильно проверить все значения на разделители в столбце в pandas и изменить неподходящие, без разделителей (@, /, -)?

Comment: не используйте циклы в pandas - это явный признак, что вы делаете что-то не так. например, обрабатываете элемент formula, а значение присваиваете всему столбцу. еще раз. забудьте о циклах, пока вы не понимаете, что делаете.  вашу проблему можно решить в одну-две строки.

Comment: и еще. возьмите за правило приводить хотя бы небольшой воспроизводимый пример данных в своем вопросе (то есть, в текстовом виде).

Comment: @ strawdog, то есть мне нужно обработать данные как отдельный список, а потом его значениями заменить уже существующие значения в данных?

Comment: Вам нужно обращаться с данными pandas так, как это и предполагается - используя векторизованный подход. то есть, вы можете обращаться с отдельным столбцом, например, как с единой сущностью. посмотрите на ответ, приведенный ниже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то надо в колонке неких строк, удалить из этих строк некие ненужные знаки. Есть `pandas` метод `.str.replace()`, он этим занимается.

```
df.Core = df.Core.str.replace('[-@/]', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: @АлексейР Сказывается мое плохое знание регулярок. После Вашего комментария погуглил и, на сколько я понял, будет работать и с `|` и без `|`, просто `|`, в данном случае излишне. Спасибо за замечание, исправил.